# Оформление телефонов ссылками по регулярному выражению

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Хочу сделать умную замену по регулярному выражению для поиска телефонов в тексте и оформления их в виде ссылок

есть тестовая строка с разными вариациями телефонов

```
 var t = '+79995260644 |sdafdsa| +7 747 526 06 44 | +7 (232) 744-33-22 | +7 (232) 333 33 33 | +7 (4569) 777 8877 | 8 (456) 777 8877';
```

есть регулярное выражение для поиска

```
  var reg = /(\+7|8)[- _]*\(?[- _]*(\d{3}[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){7}|\d\d[- _]*\d\d[- _]*\)?([- _]*\d){6})/g;
```

пробовал в начале так:

```
var r = t.replace(reg, "<a href='tel:$&'>$&</a>");
  $('#bb').html(r); //выводим результат в блок для просмотра
```

но этот метод не совершенен тем что в href не желательно наличие пробелов и прочих знаков кроме цифр.
Почитав мануалы решил сообразить по своему через функцию

```
  var v = t.replace(reg, function(str,tel,off,s) { return "<a href='tel:"+tel.replace(/[-+()]/g,"")+"'>"+tel+"</a>"; });
   $('#bb').html(v);
```

но почему то результат выходит так

```
 <a href="7">+7</a> |sdafdsa| <a href="7">+7</a> | <a href="7">+7</a> | <a href="7">+7</a> | <a href="7">+7</a> | <a href="8">8</a>
```

почему то начало резать в такой переработке, подскажите пожалуйста как правильней?

p.s: правильно ли что это выражение tel.replace(/[-+()]/g,"") удалит три, плюсы,скобки и пробелы из строки??

Comment: `/[-\s()+]/g` Вот буквально вчера сам эту проблему решал. Вот такая регулярка оставит из номера только цифры.

Comment: @AlexSazonov спасибо)) а что не так ещё с функцией в основной регулярке не подскажите? скорей всего я не понял какой то принцип действия функции как 2го аргумента что она стала так резать всё\

Comment: `.replace(/[-+()]/g,"")` удалит все круглые скобки, минусы и плюсы, но никак не пробелы, для этого и нужен `\s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Для тестовой строки
var t = '+79995260644 |sdafdsa| +7 747 526 06 44 | +7 (232) 744-33-22 | +7 (232) 333 33 33 | +7 (4569) 777 8877 | 8 (456) 777 8877';
t = t.replace(/[^\d+|]/gi, '').replace(/([+\d]+)/gi, '<a href="tel:$1">$1</a>');
console.log(t);

// Для внутритекстовой замены
t = 'Lorem ipsum +79995260644 dolor sit amet +7 747 526 06 44 consectetur adipisicing elit +7 (232) 744-33-22. Impedit a ipsa obcaecati +7 (232) 333 33 33 saepe natus similique +7 (4569) 777 8877 quas rerum? Nobis repellat, totam eos 8 (456) 777 8877 autem corporis eum ratione omnis eveniet impedit nemo accusamus.';
t = t.replace(/(\+?\d[\d ()_-]+\d)/gi, function(str) {
  return '<a href="tel:' + str.replace(/[^\d+|]/gi, '') + '">' + str + '</a>';
});
document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML = t;
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```